# How to store a multiple or a list of values returned from sp_executesql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

`UPDATE : This is what I did` -

```
   set @dyn_sql = '
                        select
                                @UserName=UserName
                        from
                        (
                        select 
                                E.ID as EmployeeID,
                                E.UserName as Username
                            from   
                                Leaderboard K
                                    inner join Employee E on  K.EmployeeId = E.Id
                                    inner join INFO KD on KD.EmployeeId=E.Id
                                    where  E.CompanyId=4
                         ) as d1'
DECLARE @leaderboards TABLE
( 
 UserName varchar(50)
) 
set @params='@Employee_Id int, @UserName varchar(200) OUTPUT'
INSERT INTO @leaderboards (UserName)
EXEC sp_executesql @dyn_sql, @params,@EmployeeId=@Employee_Id OUTPUT,@UserName = @User_Name OUTPUT

SELECT * from @leaderboards
```

`But this is not returning records although if I see the query is right and returns records..`

---

Hi all, I am executing a dynamic sql statement using sp_executesql and this is what I am doing currently -

```
EXEC sp_executesql @dyn_sql, @params,@EmployeeId=@Employee_Id OUTPUT,@UserName = @User_Name OUTPUT

SELECT @Employee_Id AS EmployeeId,@User_Name AS UserName
```

But the above only gets me single value when I am getting a list of records if I run the dynamic sql query individually.How can I store the list of values returned by execution of my dynamic sql ?
and returns records..and returns records..But this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230449/calling-a-stored-proc-from-within-a-stored-proc-and-returning-a-recordset/230468#230468

Comment: You're missing a closing single quote in your @params declaration. Also what does your dynamic SQL look like?

Comment: I have added the dynamic sql...thanks..

Comment: Why do you want to use dynamic sql? Why are you passing parameters that you don't use in your dynamic sql?

Comment: Well...Sorry for the confusion but I have changed the query little from actual one...I am using dynamic query as I am appending various where clauses depending on what I pass to stored proc..and I am passing EmployeeId parameter as one of the where clauses use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via a temp table.

**[Update]**

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
  set @sql = '
select 
    E.ID as EmployeeID, --doesn't really matter how you name them, it's the order that matters
    E.UserName as Username -- and this order should match the order of columns in the insert statement
from   
    Leaderboard K
        inner join Employee E on  K.EmployeeId = E.Id
        inner join INFO KD on KD.EmployeeId=E.Id
        where  E.CompanyId=4
'
DECLARE @LeaderBoard TABLE
( 
    EmployeeId int, 
    UserName varchar(50)
) 
INSERT INTO @LeaderBoard (EmployeeId, UserName)
exec sp_executesql @sql

select * from @LeaderBoard

--Hurray, we made it!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the results of `EXEC sp_executesql` into a temp table or table variable.

```
DECLARE  @t TABLE
(
a INT,
b INT
)
INSERT INTO @t (a,b)
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT 1, 2 UNION SELECT 3, 4 '
```

Or alternatively the dynamic SQL can access a temp table declared in the parent scope (but any temp table created in the dynamic SQL itself will be out of scope as soon as the execution finishes)

Comment: I downvoted this answer because this is not what the OP asked.

Comment: @Denis - Are you claiming somehow that this doesn't answer the question "How to store a multiple or a list of values returned from sp_executesql?"

Comment: I'm claiming that if you run it as it is it won't solve anything. The problem that you have with someone else's answers, apparently.